# Spark Scala Cassandra CSV insert into cassandra

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, intellij-idea, cassandra

Here is the code below:
Scala Version: 2.11.
Spark Version: 2.0.2.6
Cassandra Version: cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.0.1855 | DSE 5.1.3 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4

I am trying to read from CSV and write to Cassandra Table. I am new to Scala and Spark. Please correct me where I am doing wrong

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import com.datastax

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DoubleType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.UDTValue
import com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.DefaultColumnMapper


object dataframeset {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Cassandra Part

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Sample1").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    val rdd1 = sc.cassandraTable("tdata", "map")

    rdd1.collect().foreach(println)

    // Scala Read CSV Part
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val spark1 = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
      .getOrCreate()

    val df = spark1.read.format("csv")
      .option("header","true")
      .option("inferschema", "true")
      .load("/Users/tom/Desktop/del2.csv")
    import spark1.implicits._
      df.printSchema()
      val dfprev = df.select(col = "Year","Measure").filter("Category = 'Prevention'" )

//      dfprev.collect().foreach(println)
      val a = dfprev.select("YEAR")
      val b = dfprev.select("Measure")

      val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(a,b))
    collection.saveToCassandra("tdata", "map", SomeColumns("sno", "name"))

    spark1.stop()

  }

}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple constructors with the same number of parameters not allowed.
```

Cassandra Table

cqlsh:tdata> desc map

CREATE TABLE tdata.map (
    sno int PRIMARY KEY,
    name text;

I know I am missing something especially trying to write entire Data frame into Cassandra in one shot. Not I don't know what needs to be done either.

Thanks
tom

Comment: Why don't you use cqlsh copy command ?
 https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html

Comment: Thats because I dont need entire CSV, I need to apply filters and Transformations before loading them

Answer (score 1):

You can directly write a dataframe (dataset[Row] in spark 2.x) to cassandra.

You will have to define cassandra host, username and password if authentication is enabled in spark conf to connect to cassandra using somethin like

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "CASSANDRA_HOST")
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "CASSANDRA_USERNAME")            
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "CASSANDRA_PASSWORD")
```

OR

```
val spark1 = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "CASSANDRA_HOST")
      .config("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "CASSANDRA_USERNAME")            
      .config("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "CASSANDRA_PASSWORD")
      .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
      .getOrCreate()

val dfprev = df.filter("Category = 'Prevention'" ).select(col("Year").as("yearAdded"),col("Measure").as("Recording"))

dfprev .write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "map", "keyspace" -> "tdata"))
  .save()
```

[Dataframe in spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. One quick question. How do I map the data with Column Names, As "Year" in CSV should go to "YearAdded" Column and "Measure" should go to "Recording" column.

Comment: You can use `.alias` or `.as` api of spark to change column name.. I have updated my answer